# A linear order with sequences of length $\omega_0$ but without sequences of length $\omega_1$.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Given a set $S$ of cardinal $|S|\geq \omega_1$, can I give a linear < order on S such that at least one of the following two options A) or B) happen?

Option A): A.1) and A.2) are satisfied.

A.1) There are infinite countable increasing sequences.

A.2) There aren't uncountable increasing sequences.

Option B): B.1) and B.2) are satisfied.

B.1) There are infinite countable decreasing sequences.

B.2) There aren't uncountable decreasing sequences.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I understood your question correctly, so let me write this as a comment instead of an answer. Would $\omega^\text{op} \cup \omega_1$ be what you are looking for? Here $\omega^\text{op}$ is $\omega$ with the opposite order and then we append a copy of $\omega_1$. This will have an infinite decreasing sequence, but no uncountable decreasing sequences.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I have change the question. $\omega^{op}\cup \omega_1$ does not work. Maybe it is something like an Aronszanjs tree of height $\omega_1$ but with levels of cardinal $|S|$ and no uncountable branches. But maybe this is too storng and I don't need trees.

Comment: If $S$ has a total order then the set $S$ itself is a "sequence" that is both decreasing and increasing right? What kind of sequence do you exactly need?

Comment: Well, for instance I don't want $\omega_1^op$ because it has no countable infinite decreasing sequences and I don't want $\omega_1$ because it has uncountable increasing sequences.

Comment: @ASM Why would $\omega_1^\text{op}$ not have countable decreasing sequences? It contains $\omega^\text{op}$ for example... Also, I still do not understand your question then. In 1: what does it mean for a sequence to be "always possible"? In 2: the "or" is confusing. I suggest you fix one of increasing/decreasing and phrase your question in that sense, if there is an example for one, there will be one for the other by just considering the opposite order. So you are not limiting yourself to anything.

Comment: I understand the question to be: which sets $S$ can be equipped with a linear order which has both increasing and decreasing $\omega$-sequences, but no increasing or decreasing sequences indexed by uncountable ordinals (equivalently, neither increasing nor decreasing $\omega_1$-sequences). An easy example of such a linear order is $\mathbb{R}$. In fact,  $S$ admits such an order iff $\aleph_0\leq |S|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$. If this answers the question you meant to ask, I'll write a more complete answer.

Comment: I have edit the question. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you mean by "sequence". In this answer, I assume you're talking about sequences indexed by ordinals. So, e.g., an increasing sequence is $(x_\beta)_{\beta<\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $x_\beta < x_\gamma$ for all $\beta<\gamma<\alpha$.

Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable cardinal (viewed as an initial ordinal). The linear order $\omega^{\mathrm{op}}+\kappa$ satisfies your Option B. Indeed, the copy of $\omega^{\mathrm{op}}$ is a countable decreasing sequence. And any decreasing sequence includes only finitely many elements of $\kappa$ (since $\kappa$ is well-ordered), followed by elements of $\omega^{\mathrm{op}}$, so it is at most countable. In fact, an ordinal-indexed decreasing sequence in this order cannot be indexed by any ordinal greater than $\omega$.

The order $\omega^{\mathrm{op}}+\kappa$ has cardinality $\kappa$, so if $S$ is any set of cardinality $\kappa$, we can equip $S$ with a linear order isomorphic to $\omega^{\mathrm{op}}+\kappa$.

Similarly, $\kappa^{\mathrm{op}} + \omega$ satisifes your Option A, and any set of cardinality $\kappa$ can be equipped with a linear order isomorphic to $\kappa^{\mathrm{op}} + \omega$.

---

A more interesting question is to determine the possible cardinalities of linear orders satisfying both Option A and Option B. That is, linear orders with infinite increasing and descending sequences, but no uncountable increasing or decreasing sequences.

Let me first point out:

**Theorem 1:** Every infinite linear order has an infinite increasing sequence or an infinite decreasing sequence.

*Proof:* Let $(L,<)$ be a linear order, and choose a well-order $\lessdot$ on $L$ (which may have nothing to do with $<$). Now for each pair $a\neq b$ in $L$ with $a\lessdot b$, color $\{a,b\}$ blue if $a<b$, and color $\{a,b\}$ red if $b<a$. By [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem),  $L$ has an infinite monochromatic subset $L'\subseteq L$. Note that $L$ is well-ordered by $\lessdot$, so we can naturally view it as an infinite ordinal-index sequence. If it is monochromatic blue, it is an increasing sequence, and if it is monochromatic red, it is a decreasing sequence. $\square$

Now suppose $(L,<)$ is an infinite linear order with no uncountable increasing or decreasing sequences. By Theorem 1, $L$ has either an infinite increasing sequence or an infinite decreasing sequence. Define $L' = L+L^{\mathrm{op}}$. Then $|L'| = |L|$, $L'$ has both infinite increasing and infinite decreasing sequences (one in $L$ and one in $L^{\mathrm{op}}$), and $L'$ has no uncountable increasing or decreasing sequences (since the intersection of such a sequence with $L$ or with $L^{\mathrm{op}}$ would again be uncountable).

This shows that the problem reduces to: What are the possible cardinalities of infinite linear orders with no uncountable increasing or decreasing sequences? Let's call such a linear order "short".

It's a classic fact that $\mathbb{R}$ has no uncountable increasing or decreasing sequences (because it has a countable dense set $\mathbb{Q}$). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3737967/7062), for example. So there is a short linear order of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Now for any $\kappa$ with $\aleph_0\leq \kappa\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, let $L\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subset of cardinality $\kappa$. The induced order on $L$ is short, because any sequence in $L$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Ok, so we can get short linear orders of any infinite cardinality $\kappa\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$. What about $\kappa>2^{\aleph_0}$? The answer is no, by a strengthening of Theorem 1.

**Theorem 2:** Every linear order $(L,<)$ with $|L|>2^{\aleph_0}$ has an uncountable increasing sequence or an uncountable decreasing sequence.

*Proof:* Same as Theorem 1, but this time we apply the [Erdös-Rado theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Rado_theorem). As a special case of Erdös-Rado, we have $(2^{\aleph_0})^+\rightarrow (\aleph_1)^2_{\aleph_0}$. In English, this says that if $S$ is a set with $|S|>2^{\aleph_0}$ and we color each pair from $S$ by one of a countable number of colors, then we can find a monochromatic subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$. Applying the same coloring as in the proof of Theorem 1, we find an uncountable subset of $L$, well-ordered by $\lessdot$, which is either an increasing sequence or a decreasing sequence in $L$.

This shows that if a linear order is short, then it has cardinality $\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Thank you Alex and Mark. Please Alex, could you elaborate the end of your answer? I'm very weak on set theory and logic.

Comment: @ASM Sure, I can elaborate on the last paragraph when I have time later. Just to be clear, do you understand the first half of my answer, about getting option A or option B? If not, let me know what's not clear to you.

Comment: Yes, thank you Alex.

Comment: @ASM I've added more details to my answer.

Comment: +1. Another example for Option A is the lexicographic order on $\omega\times (\kappa^{op}).$

Comment: Thank you very much Alex.